# MOD_WSGI Daemon Mode multiple hanging httpd processes

Tags: apache-2.2, process, mod-wsgi

As a python developer I had some understanding of how mod_wsgi works, which is that it launches a new python process with each request.  That is not to say a new httpd process, rather a single httpd process running something like

```
python /path/to/my/wsgi.py <param> <param>
```

My understanding of daemon mode is that if process=1 (default), a single process with 15 threads is used to handle a request.  But what happens to the httpd process when the request is served?

The bigger question here is that in my logs, I'm seeing up to 30 httpd processes consuming over 3G of Memory.  What can this be an indication of? Requests with code that never terminated? apache borking a request and never completing it?

**Edit**

I ps aux'd httpd to find about 22 processes.  When I strace'd, most of them were just waiting, but one keeps printing the following, over and over:

```
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
wait4(-1, 0x7fff9d6990ec, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
```

Which to me looks like SQL?

Answer (score 0):

It was a miss-understanding of the apache config.  I made an assumption that mod_wsgi was running as a daemon, when it was running in embedded mode.  The apache worker.c section set the number of processes to 8 with an expansion of 25 and that's why there were so many stand-by processes.